# Symbols function definition is void: split-window-side-by-side

Tags: c#, emacs, read-eval-print-loop

I am new to Emacs (using version 24.1.1 on Windows) and I altered my .emacs file by including 
the code below which I found here: [CSharpRepl emacs integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207068/csharprepl-emacs-integration)

```
(defun csharp-repl ()
  "Open a new side-by-side window and start CSharpRepl in it."
  (interactive)
  (split-window-side-by-side)
  (other-window 1)
  (comint-run "C:\\Program Files\\CSRepl\\CSRepl.exe"))

(global-set-key [f11] 'csharp-repl)
```

When I hit F11 I end up getting an error saying "Symbol's function definition is void: split-window-side-by-side". If I leave (split-window-side-by-side) and (other-window 1) out, the C# REPL will open but in one window, which isn't really what I want.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're not looking for `split-window-vertically` ? In my emacs24, I can't see anything under M-x that matches `split-window-side-by-side`.

Comment: Wow, this worked, thank you so much. When you say in your Emacs 'you can't see anything', what do you mean by that ? Where could I have looked this up ?

Comment: I went `M-x split-` and then pressed tab. Emacs showed me all the interactive functions available using auto-complete

Comment: If you know which keyboard shortcut would have done the same thing, which in this case is `C-x 3`, then you could have run `C-h k C-x 3`, and Emacs would have give you the name of the function run, which you could then slot into your elisp.